# Is it possible to hide SQL connections from 3rd party developers?

Tags: c#, sql-server

We hired a 3rd party to finish a C# web project for us and they need access to our SQL database. How can we hide our user name and password from them but still give them access?

Efforts so far include:

- Creating a WCF only to realize that we do not have that much control of the servers hosting our web site.
- Creating a DLL but was able to find the actual connection string by digging through the Watch window at a break point while debugging.
- Encrypting the connection strings within the web config. By using the Watch window at a break point, I can find the decrypted connection string.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new database and change the user name and password and let them access that.

Comment: If we had just one database, your answer would be easy. We have dozens of databases accessed via one server with multiple linked servers.

Comment: And you have no test environment at all?

Comment: I was talking about our test environment.

Comment: Create a new user just for them to use?

Answer (score 2):

Use SSPI eg, windows credentials and give the user that hosts the process access.

Sounds like its a web app, give the application pool account access.

Comment: Correct ... about this being for a web app. Also, I'm not familiar with SSPI and have been reading about it since you responded.

Comment: This is the correct answer - grant access to the windows identity of their process instead of providing a username and password.  You can also create a separate application pool just for their application so as to not grant other applications access to the database.

Comment: Basically use windows auth. Eg don't pass a username or password

Comment: Basically, I ask our web host vendor to assign the credentials and I can change this `connectionString="server=SqlTest;database=TestDb;uid=a4;pwd=a5;` to this 
`connectionString="server=SqlTest;database=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;`?

Answer (score 0):

- Write a new class, that gives them acces to your database (to the relations they need).
- Create some views in your database, that they can acces with a new user, that doesn't have that much privileges.